# Check if a string format a word

Tags: python, machine-learning, text-classification

I am building a python text classification application. In the app the user provides a small sentence (or a single word) and we classify his sentence. The problem I'm facing is to find a way to check if his string format a word or a group of words.

Examples of users inputs:

1) "asdfasdfa"

2) "This is adsfgafdga"

The example 1 is not a word so I want to raise an Error, also the example 2 contains a non-word string in it so I want to raise an Error too.

Correct Examples:

1) "Hello"

2) "This is good"

Is there a way to do that without a list of words or someone know an API to do that?

Comment: provide an example of input and output, and also what did you try already

Comment: Are you trying to validate whether a particular word is actually a word or checking if the user input is a phrase (more than one word) or doing both?

Comment: I am trying to do both of them. And i already provided you 2 examples one of each case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One extensive method is to create a list and store the dictionary words in it. First perform a split on the user input to singularly extract each word off a phrase using a `phrase.split()`.

```
words = phrase.split() 
// words : ['This', 'is', 'good'] 

len(words) 
// number of words : 3
```

Run a loop according to the number of words in the phrase if the result is greater than 1.
And then its a mere matter of checking whether the word is present in the list using the following.

```
if "word" in dictionary_words:
   print "Word is available"
```

There's a neat [XML version of the dictionary words](http://wordlist.aspell.net/) you can use instead of the list.

For a more sophisticated solution, you can try incorporating an API like [PyEnchant](https://github.com/rfk/pyenchant) that provisions a spell checking library. For further details in this regard, you can check it out and do a `pip install pyenchant`and import it.

```
>>> import enchant
>>> help(enchant)
```

Comment: I already try it but i don't want to implement with this way. I need something automated.

Comment: @dapo Check out my modified answer above. Other than the rigorous dictionary listing and validation, using an API would be a solution at hand

Answer (score 0):

This will split the string using spaces and we will count the number of groupings of characters in your string separated by spaces. If the length of this list is 1, then we only had a single word in the string input.

```
string = "This is adsfgafdga"
if len(string.split()) == 1:
    is_word = True
else: is_word = False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex as follows:

```
import re

# if word is delimited by white space

is_word = len(re.split('[\s]', your_sentence)) ==1

# if word is delimited by non alphanumeric characters

is_word = len(re.split('[^a-zA-Z]', your_sentence)) ==1
```